# Run Python Flask application with nginx Unit

Tags: python, nginx, flask

I played around today with the nginx Unit application server and Python 3. It works fine as long as I run a simple WSGI application, but I won't work (404) when trying to use Flask...

nginx config:

```
upstream unit_backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:8300;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    server_name _;

    location / {

    }

    location /unittest {
            proxy_pass http://unit_backend;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

Unit config:

```
{
"listeners": {
    "*:8300": {
        "application": "test"
    }
},

"applications": {
    "test": {
        "type": "python 3.5",
        "processes": 4,
        "user": "noisefloor",
        "group": "noisefloor",
        "path": "/home/noisefloor/code/unit_test",
        "module": "wsgi"
    }
},

"access_log": "/var/log/access.log"
}
```

wsgi.py which works when opening http://127.0.0.1/unittest in the browser:

```
from datetime import datetime

def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain; charset=utf-8')]
    start_response(status, headers)
    text = 'Hello World @ {}'.format(datetime.now())
    return [text.encode('utf-8')]
```

When the wsgi.py is as follows:

```
from flask import Flask

    application = Flask(__name__)

    @application.route('/')
    def test():
        return 'Hello Flask!'
```

It get the 404, but I see what I expect to see when calling http://127.0.0.1:8300 - so it basically work, it just don't get why it won't work when calling http://127.0.0.1/unittest

Answer (score 1):

The question is old but i believe it is worth answering(as its one of the first indexed by google if you type Nginx Unit).

> Since you didn't specified any URI in your `proxy_pass` directive the
>   request is passed to your flask application with `/unittest` URI and you
>   clearly don't have any route specified in flask application apart from
>   the `"/"`